# $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR' string and changing subnets

Tags: php, ip

I want to expand the IP range that my ~$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'~ check for. The following works and only allows the 10.0.4.* subnet access to the site:

```
$chk = "10.0.4.";
if( substr($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'],0,strlen($chk)) !== $chk)
    $wgGroupPermissions['*']['read'] = false;
```

When I modify the `$chk` string to open the site to my entire local network I end up opening the site to the entire world.

```
$chk = "10.0.";
if( substr($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'],0,strlen($chk)) !== $chk)
    $wgGroupPermissions['*']['read'] = false;
```

I only want my local subnet 10.0.. to have read access to the site. How do I do this?

Comment: You could alternatively use the [strncmp()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strncmp.php) function to clean up your code a bit.

Comment: Also, I think the best way to handle this is not in your PHP application, but rather in your firewall (preferably) or at least in your apache config.

Comment: I like the fact that when trying to access the site externally it asks for a login but when you're on our network you can browse the site.

Comment: @jedwards is my code not clean enough? How would you simplify it?

Comment: Gotcha, then the two alternatives I suggested wouldn't work.  But back to the question, I see no reason why your second code block wouldn't work provided the first did.

Comment: It's fine, I was just suggesting using a different comparison function to eliminate the nested string functions.  [Example](http://pastebin.com/U6FQXr8A)

Comment: Right! It should totally work. Gerrrr.

Answer (score 1):

Using mask is a better way than spliting strings:

```
function testSubnet($ip, $subnet, $mask) {
    $ip = ip2long($ip);
    $subnet = ip2long($subnet);
    $mask = ip2long($mask);
    return ($ip & $mask) == ($subnet & $mask);
}

var_dump(testSubnet('10.0.0.1', '10.0.0.0', '255.255.255.0'));
var_dump(testSubnet('10.0.0.2', '10.0.0.0', '255.255.255.0'));
var_dump(testSubnet('10.0.1.1', '10.0.0.0', '255.255.255.0'));
var_dump(testSubnet('10.0.1.1', '10.0.0.0', '255.255.0.0'));
```

---

In this case:

```
if(testSubnet($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], '10.0.4.0', '255.255.255.0')) {
    // Anything, blablabla...
}
```

Comment: I'm at a loss for how to integrate this into my current setup. Any clues would help. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you just do:

```
$z = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

function check($ip, $octet = 2) {
    $allow = explode(".", "10.0.0.1");
    $ipa = explode(".", $ip);

    for($i = 0; $i < $octet; $i++) {
        $ch .= $ipa[$i];
        $ah .= $allow[$i];
    }

   return $ch == $ah;
 }

echo check($z);
```

Where $octet is the amount of octets you want to match.. The default is 2.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `header()` function?
Try this.

```
$allowed_ip = "10.0.4";
if (!strstr($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'],$allowed_ip))
   header("Location: login.php");
   // include("login.php");

/* The user will be redirected to another page or you could
always include your login.php page and just continue from there. */
```